# check Levenshtein distance of each row to other row in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text, levenshtein-distance

I have two data frame :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['hello world', 'world hello'], 'id': [11,31]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['hello', 'world'], 'id': [13,11]})
```

I want to calculate Levenshtein distance of each text row in df1 with df2 and if score >=0.9 then remove that record from df1.

What I have tried :

```
def check_levenshtein_distance(df1,df2):
    score = []
    with tqdm(total=df1.shape[0]) as pbar:    
        for index, row in df1.iterrows():
            for index1, row1 in df2.iterrows():
                dis = Levenshtein.ratio(str(row['text']), str(row1['text']))
                if dis>=0.9:
                    score.append(index)          
            pbar.update(1)
    return check

data_d = check_levenshtein_distance(df1, df2)
```

and after

```
df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[data_d])
```

Is there any better and fast method in pure pandas to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've indicated that the previous solution resulted in out of memory issues (which isn't surprising since we're generating every possible combination) I have another suggestion. It will be a bit slower but it works without creating every possible combination so it will take less memory. I do want to urge you to reconsider if dataframes are the best way to go. Dataframes are usually not the best solution when it comes to handling large quantities of text...

```py
import pandas
import Levenshtein

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"text": ["hello world", "world hello"], "id": [11, 31]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"test": ["hello", "world", "hello word"], "id": [13, 11, 12]})

# Make sure the types of the columns are correct
df1["text"] = df1["text"].astype(str)
df2["test"] = df2["test"].astype(str)


def filter_rows(row: pandas.Series) -> pandas.Series:

    # By default, the row doesn't need to be removed
    row["remove"] = False

    # Loop over the texts in the other dataframe
    for text in df2["test"].values:

        # Check the distance
        if Levenshtein.ratio(row["text"], text) >= 0.9:

            # Indicate that this row needs to be removed
            row["remove"] = True

            # Return the row, so don't look any futher!
            return row

    # If we didn't return yet, just return the default
    return row


# Apply the function (this will create a new column called "remove", indicating if a row should be removed)
df1 = df1.apply(filter_rows, axis=1)

# Remove the rows that have the remove indication, and drop the column
df1 = df1.loc[~df1["remove"]].drop(columns=["remove"])
```

**Previous answer:**

Try it this way:

```py
import pandas
import Levenshtein

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"text": ["hello world", "world hello"], "id": [11, 31]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"test": ["hello", "world", "hello word"], "id": [13, 11, 12]})

# Create all possible combinations by joining the dataframes on a fictional key
df1["key"] = 0
df2["key"] = 0
df = df1.merge(df2, on="key").drop(columns=["key"])

# Calculate the distances for all possible combinations
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda row: Levenshtein.ratio(str(row["text"]), str(row["test"])), axis=1)

# Use the distances as a filter
df1.loc[df1["id"].isin(df.loc[df["distance"] < 0.9, "id_x"])]
```

Comment: This is a really good solution, although my files are quite big and it's giving memory error(automatic killed process on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Is my understanding correct that you want to drop any row `i` in `df1` for which at least one element of `df2['test']` has a Levenshtein distance >= 0.9 to `df1.loc[i, 'text']`?

If so, then you could try:

```
df1 = df1[df1['text'].map(lambda s: not any(Levenshtein.ratio(s, t) >= 0.9 for t in df2['test']))]
```